# How to simplify MVC pattern for a demo purpose?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, methodology

I have to set up a Asp.net demo using MVC 4 in a web application in order to help decision for a product that currently don't use this pattern. The model, view and controller should be simple, I just have two or three entities and a few pages.

I suppose I don't have to implement the whole infrastructure with services, repositories, etc. So how could I simplify the MVC components without loosing those advantages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MVC components aren't related to the data access strategy which you can use. To put together a quick demo (or a simple application) you can leave the data access in the same project but eventually split that out etc.

You can use something like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to map from your entities to your view models if you want to put that level of abstraction in. You can also use EntityFramework contexts in the controllers to avoid additional levels of abstraction and only put in a simple interface/abstraction into one controller to show unit test ability.

Small examples of different patterns which could be used in the application is probably the way to go for the demo/presentation and not worry too much about putting them in all over the place. Remember the presentation and the delivery of information is as important, it not more, than the demo code itself.